# export nested XML file from access. need XML file with nodes

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba

I need to create an XML file from Access. It has to have a relational node type format.

For instance:

```
<Item>
   <description></description>
   <colors>
         <blue>
         <green>
   </colors>
</item>
```

The data for the items is in a table. The colors are in another. I have reference IDs so I can join them.

How/can this be done. I have looked all over and see how to export a table, but not the nested type of file.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `SELECT` query which uses the reference ID to join your items table with the colors table.

Once you have a query which gathers the information correctly, export its data to XML from the Access user interface.

[image: Export query to XML]

If that gives you the XML you want, you can automate the export operation from VBA using the [Application.ExportXML Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193212%28v=office.14%29.aspx).  Notice that method offers a host of options to tweak the XML.  But the export might be as simple as this ...

```
Application.ExportXML acExportQuery, "YourQuery", _
    "C:\SomeFolder\YourQuery.xml"
```

Comment: [code]<testExport>
<ID>1</ID>
<Description>Test Item</Description>
<ColorName>Blue</ColorName>
</testExport>
<testExport>
<ID>1</ID>
<Description>Test Item</Description>
<ColorName>Green</ColorName>
</testExport>
<testExport>
<ID>1</ID>
<Description>Test Item</Description>
<ColorName>Blue</ColorName>
</testExport>
</dataroot>[/code]

Answer (score 1):

Below is a sample of what I use to query for data and then export the results to a flat file.  I have adapted it somewhat to what you may need.

```
 On Error GoTo Err_My_Click
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
 Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MyTable", dbOpenDynaset)

 If (rs.RecordCount <> 0) Then
   rs.MoveFirst

   Open "C:\Export\XML__MyFile.xml" For Output As #1

   Do While rs.EOF = False
     TempExportCount = TempExportCount + 1

     Print #1, "<Item>"
     Print #1, "    <description>" & rs.Fields("[Description]").value & "</description>"
     Print #1, "</Item>"

     rs.MoveNext
   Loop
 End If

Exit_My_Click:
  On Error Resume Next
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Close 1#
  Exit Sub
Err_My_Click:
  If (Err.Number = 76) Then
    MsgBox ("The program could not save the txt file." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Make sure you have the following folder created: C:\Export\")
  Else
    MsgBox (Err.Description)
  End If
  Resume Exit_My_Click
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the attached to produce a 3 million line nested xml in about five minutes.

There are two key items,

1) a simple piece of VB,

```
Public Function Export_ListingData()

    Dim objOtherTbls As AdditionalData

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
    Set objOtherTbls = Application.CreateAdditionalData
    objOtherTbls.Add "ro_address"
    objOtherTbls.Add "ro_buildingDetails"
    objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessDetails"
    objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessExtras"
    objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessExtrasAccounts"
    objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessExtrasAccom"
    objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessExtrasAccom2"

    Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
                DataSource:="ro_business", _
                DataTarget:="C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Conversions\ListData.xml", _
                AdditionalData:=objOtherTbls
Exit_Here:
        MsgBox "Export_ListingData completed"
        Exit Function
ErrorHandle:
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        Resume Exit_Here
End Function
```

2) Linking the tables in relationship manager using joins from primary to FOREIGN keys.

If their are no relationships the code will produce a sequential xml file, if there are
relationships between primary keys you will get a 31532 error and the data export will fail.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer verbatim to multiple questions.  If the questions are actually the same, flag to close them as duplicates.